# Getting Count is not number error on command line when Monkey testing

Tags: android

Monkey testing using command prompt and getting error `count is not number`.

Using this command:

```
adb shell monkey -p package name -v 500
```

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: Looking for a solution to this as well. Anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sequence.

```
adb shell monkey -v 500 -p package name
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with copying the command directly from the web browser as sometimes, invisible characters like `newline` also get copied (and the space characters copied are different from the ones generated with the spacebar).

Try manually typing the command on the terminal and see if the error still happens.